# How do I change the End Frame in an animation without changing the max frames in other animations within a character?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

In the dope sheet I selected Action Editor in the dropdown menu to animate my character with multiple different animations and they all take up different amount of frames. But when I change the End Frame of one animation, it changes all the other animations' End Frame to the one I inserted to that one animation.

**Is there a way to change only one animation's End Frame?**

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

The `start frame` and `end frame` are properties of the scene. That's is why they're located in the *scene* section of the properties area. Each scene has its own (but exactly one) *start* and *end frame*.

Actions have no start and end frame. They are automatically starting on their first keyframe and ending on their last keyframe. If you add an action to the [NLA editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html) these are the frames which are used for the length of the action. (You can still trim the actions used frame range in the NLA editor.)

Comment: You mean « *They are automatically starting on their first **key**frame* »?